# How to delete or disable android airplane mode

Tags: android

i am trying to delete or disable airplane mode in rooted android device.it is possible or not ? how can i do it cording or anything.

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
```

am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false

Comment: hi use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537467/enable-airplane-mode-on-all-api-levels-programmatically-android

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17){
try{
    Intent intentAirplaneMode = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
    intentAirplaneMode.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intentAirplaneMode);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Log.e("exception", e + "");
}
}
else{
Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Comment: this code only open wireless and network window.not enable airplane mode

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/AirplaneModeEnabler.java#91):

```
// 0 for disabling, 1 for enabling
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", 0);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

To do this you have to get

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>`

in your manifest and run your app as a system app.

Comment: what's your phone api level, what do you mean by you can't add uses-permission to manifest?